# Sublime Text 3 Disable Context Autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, indentation

Sublime Text 3 has this really annoying habit of autocompleting my comments even after I've already closed them. So if I write

```
/*|*/
```

where the bar is my cursor, and then I press tab so that I can put an indentation following my initial * symbol, I want it to look like this:

```
/*    |*/    (assume that the bar is my cursor and tab of size 4 between *s)
```

Instead, I get this:

```
/*
|
*/*/
```

This is extremely annoying; I like to customize my comments to fit the bill of whatever I'm working on. I know I can ignore a preference/package in my User settings, but I don't know *which* one to ignore. This is an obscure context and I can't find which option triggers it. Ideally I'd like to keep autocomplete for other things, but it's not something I rely on heavily so losing it in the process would be no great loss.

EDIT - Tips on removing auto-commenting whenever I press 'Enter' on a "//" comment line would be nice too. What I'd like is

```
//
|
```

and what I (frustratingly) get is

```
//
//|
```

Comment: To clearify: the autocompletion does not popup, but it does automatically insert something, when pressing tab? And you want to disable that behavior?

Comment: @r-stein Yeah, that's exactly it. It doesn't show me the incoming change, but performs it when I press Enter nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't add pictures, so you need to click on the link;

[find docblockr settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5wnl.jpg)

[add setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roD4j.png)

"jsdocs_extend_double_slash": false

```
//
//|
```

you can get is

```
//
|
```

Other settings; you need to view the file:
Preferences->Package Settings->DocBlockr->Settings-Default

Comment: It's weird, there's no option to disable comment blocks (the "/* */" blocks). Thanks for this though, introduced me to the DocBlockr and some of its tricks, which I do like in general!

Answer (score 1):

As addition to @baijunyao 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37375253/5963435):
Taking a short look into the DocBlockr keymap they check no settings for inserting `\n*/` when pressing `tab`. However you can easily add a keybinding to your `Key Bindings - User`:

```js
{
    "keys": ["tab"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\t"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "comment" }
    ]
},
```

This keybinding could be expressed as "If I press `tab` and I am inside a comment, then insert a tab.".

Comment: That did the trick! I'm still unfamiliar with the grammar of sublime-<> files and the like, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is caused by the DocBlockr package, it contains a keymap that binds the <kbd>enter</kbd> key to create a snippet when it is in a comment scope. The fix is to uninstall this package.

Comment: That's unfortunate, since DocBlockr has a bunch of other really nice features and in general is very useful. Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way it’s to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>.
It permit to ignore all events as auto-completion triggers and simply write an indentation space.